# Unable to find registered toolchains of certain type in new bazel module

Tags: bazel, toolchain

I'm writing Bazel rules for Apple's new config language [pkl](https://pkl-lang.org/index.html). My repo for the new rules is [here](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl).

I am attempting to register toolchains and use those for the 'pkl_eval' rule that would essentially call 'pkl eval ...' on some set of .pkl files.

I have a toolchain type setup [here](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl/blob/main/pkl/BUILD.bazel#L1). It is depended on by the pkl_eval rule [here](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl/blob/main/pkl/pkl_invocations.bzl#L41). My repository rules/macros for creating and registering the toolchain repos in the module are [here](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl/blob/main/pkl/pkl_toolchain.bzl#L105).

When I attempt to build the target declared [here](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl/blob/main/test/BUILD.bazel#L3), I get this output:

```bash
[clatham@clatham-dev rules_pkl]$ bazel build //... --toolchain_resolution_debug='//pkl:toolchain_type'
ERROR: /home/clatham/code/rules_pkl/test/BUILD.bazel:3:9: While resolving toolchains for target //test:test_eval (71dc0e2): No matching toolchains found for types //pkl:toolchain_type.
To debug, rerun with --toolchain_resolution_debug='//pkl:toolchain_type'
If platforms or toolchains are a new concept for you, we'd encourage reading https://bazel.build/concepts/platforms-intro.
Target //pkl:toolchain_type up-to-date (nothing to build)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//test:test_eval' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.055s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
[clatham@clatham-dev rules_pkl]$
```

I have a feeling this is a silly mistake somewhere, but I just can't spot it. My host constraints should satisfy at least one of the platforms I [have](https://github.com/storm-of-fists/rules_pkl/blob/main/pkl/pkl_toolchain.bzl#L8). Here is the file contents:

```
[clatham@clatham-dev local_config_platform]$ cat constraints.bzl 
# DO NOT EDIT: automatically generated constraints list for local_config_platform
# Auto-detected host platform constraints.
HOST_CONSTRAINTS = [
  '@platforms//cpu:x86_64',
  '@platforms//os:linux',
]
```

Comment: What's the output when you rerun with `--toolchain_resolution_debug='//pkl:toolchain_type'` like the message suggests?